# Java static List

Tags: java, android

I want to pass a static list through an interface.
So that I can execute the following code.

```
updateSingleItem(new InformationListModule(getNameByUUID(uid), value));
```

I am looking for the cleanest way to create a static list where I can output the name based on an ID. I want to pass this list to different classes.

How can I create a static list with which I can execute the command "getNameByUUID(uid)".

Maybe someone can tell me what is the cleanest solution and give a small example.
would be glad.

Vielen Lieben dank.

Comment: re *How can I create a static list with which I can execute the command "getNameByUUID(uid)"*  Where does the list fit in to that?  The single argument is a uid, which is not a list.  You haven't told us what it returns, but it seems like it might return a "name", which is probably not a list.

Comment: Data like: (Data of BLE services)

int id,
String name,
String identifier,

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent a database. Perhaps just... use a database. Other alternatives: java.util.HashMap.

Comment: I agree.  For a smallish (less than a few thousand maybe) entries that can be wired into source code, just use a hash map keyed by 'id'.  Or if the 'id' are assigned more-or-less contiguously, a simple array might do the job.  But you need to describe your problem in much more detail.

Comment: No, this does not meet the requirements of a database. We only need static variables. These are only used to resolve a BLE message.

Answer (score 0):

I have now implemented it this way.

```
public abstract class BluetoothUUIDs {
/* UUID SERVICES */
public static final HashMap<String, String> BLE_SERVICE_UUID_NAME;
public static final HashMap <String, String> BLE_SERVICE_UUID_TYPE;
/* UUID ATTRIBUTES */
...
{
    /* UUID SERVICES TO NAME */
    BLE_SERVICE_UUID_NAME = new HashMap<>();
    .....
    BLE_SERVICE_UUID_TYPE.put("1800","org.bluetooth.service.generic_access");
    ...
```

I don't know if it's the best, but it's a way.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an EnumMap.

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

public enum UUIDs {
    UUID_1("1800", "org.bluetooth.service.generic_access"),
    // additional UUID‘s..

    private final String uuid;
    private final String name;

    UUIDs(String uuid, String name) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private static final EnumMap<UUIDs, String> uuidToName = new EnumMap<>(UUIDs.class);
    private static final EnumMap<UUIDs, String> uuidToType = new EnumMap<>(UUIDs.class);

    static {
        for (UUIDs uuid : UUIDs.values()) {
            uuidToName.put(uuid, uuid.getName());
            uuidToType.put(uuid, uuid.getUuid());
        }
    }

    public static String getNameByUuid(String uuid) {
        for (UUIDs u : UUIDs.values()) {
            if (u.getUuid().equals(uuid)) {
                return u.getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getUuidByName(String name) {
        for (UUIDs u : UUIDs.values()) {
            if (u.getName().equals(name)) {
                return u.getUuid();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can access the EnumMap in other classes by calling the methods `getNameByUuid` and `getUuidByName`.

```
String name = UUIDs.getNameByUuid("1800");
String uuid = UUIDs.getUuidByName("org.bluetooth.service.generic_access");
```

This is a suggestion you could try/use.